Ethics based on maximizing "understanding"
Can we declare that the ultimate moral good is to maximize understanding of deep truths, and all else follows from that?
The main thing that could morally distinguish humans from other animals is that we have more capable brains. Specifically, our brains are able to form abstract models that allow us to understand more of the world than other animals can. The models allow us to answer "how?" and "why?" in a deeper way than any other animal.
Understanding-based ethics is about understanding of deep truths. Making a database of all the blades of grass in your yard, for example, constitutes truth but is very shallow. Deep understanding is more than just a list of facts. It's about the deep structures tying different ideas together fundamentally.


Lying would be wrong under this system because it directly works against mutual understanding of the truth.
Murder would be wrong under this system because it deprives the world of a mind that could understand. The greater the mind lost, the worse the offense; this is why it is worse to kill a human than a raccoon. But everyone has their own unique viewpoint and experiences, so it is wrong to lose any life.
Lesser crimes such as stealing would be wrong because they damage the harmonious functioning of society, which is necessary to support the pursuit of truth. In a poor society, people have difficulty deeply understanding the world around them because they are too focused on scrounging for subsistence.
Education, research, and free and honest discourse would be ends in themselves.


Say the "best" moral system is X. Suppose, contrarily, that understanding-based ethics is not X. But by pursuing understanding-based ethics, we would best be able to learn of X. The more we understand about moral matters, and the more widespread this understanding among everyone in society, the more widespread adherence to X would become.
So that even if understanding-based ethics is not the best moral system, it would be the best way to reach the best moral system, and transition to it once it is known! So by following understanding-based ethics, we get to hedge our bets.
Understanding-based ethics sidesteps some of the problems of utilitarianism. If you could spend the rest of your life in a delusion box that grants you a feeling of happiness in a virtual world you can't distinguish from reality, should you? Utilitarianism says yes, probably. Understanding-based ethics says absolutely not.
Suffering is just an indicator of a problem, like the "check engine" light on your dashboard. The goal isn't to make the "check engine" light go off; the goal is to fix the engine.

People can and have performed a lot of horrific experiments on other people in the name of increasing understanding. It probably wouldn't be too hard to argue that this can be done without much damage to the "harmonious functioning of society", or that the benefit is greater. It would be hard to avoid that if your ultimate focus is on increasing understanding, rather than reducing suffering and increasing happiness or well-being. Utilitarianism also implies a secondary goal of trying to reduce suffering you don't directly cause, which understanding-based ethics would be more indifferent to.

@NotThatGuy Such experiments were usually done without informed consent, i.e. the subjects did not understand what was being done to them. The Tuskegee experiment was like that. That goes directly contrary to understanding-based ethics.

@causative So would it be fine to do a horrific experiment with informed consent? "That goes directly contrary to understanding-based ethics" - does it? You didn't exactly define the metric you're trying to optimise. If you're trying to maximise understanding over time, or create the maximum understanding for the greatest number of people, it would be trivial to justify this. Or what other metric are you using? Under this framework, what would morally obligate you to make someone understand something right now? Also, why is consent be required at all? They can understand without consenting.

@NotThatGuy "would it be fine to do a horrific experiment with informed consent" - couldn't be that horrible if they're informed and consenting, could it? "They can understand without consenting" - that wouldn't have worked in the Tuskegee experiment because if the subjects had understood they would have just refused to comply and the experiment could not have continued. Evil usually cannot survive without deception.

@causative Desperate people could be convinced to consent to pretty much anything (even without you compelling them, e.g. offer poor people money). And there are many, many experiments you are able to do on people that don't require them to comply. Consider asylums, for example, where doctors would be able to just strap patients down and do whatever (and many doctor have done exactly that in the past). You're picking one example of an experiment that required consent, to try to make the case that experiments without informed consent "cannot survive", but that doesn't follow.

@NotThatGuy But we've mostly stopped just strapping patients down in asylums and experimenting on them without their consent. Why? Because of media publicizing such abuses, causing a public reaction against them. Letting the light in tends to stop evil.

@causative The public reaction was not "this doesn't increase our understanding", it was "this causes suffering". That is, the actual moral opposition is based in something closer to utilitarianism rather than being understanding-based. Having knowledge about something is "necessary" to be able to oppose it, but to oppose it, it's also necessary to breathe and eat and communicate, and we aren't going to say we should have a moral system that's breath-based, food-based or communication-based. Those are simply the foundation that enables you to get the actual thing you want (less suffering).

@NotThatGuy Was the public reaction the same when the experiments were done on something that lacks human understanding, such as mice? No; for mice it was lesser. The public got upset about the treatment of psychiatric patients because (1) they understood what was being done, and (2) it was being done to thinking beings also capable of such understanding. Note that a major reason why killing of animals is considered by some to be more okay than killing of humans is because the animals (according to those who think this) do not have an understanding of their mortality.

Suffering is just an indicator of a problem, like the "check engine" light on your dashboard. The goal isn't to make the "check engine" light go off; the goal is to fix the engine.

@causative "it was being done to thinking beings also capable of such understanding" - I think you're turning your own framework on its head. You talk of ethics based on maximising understanding - how does this apply to whether it's okay to torture-but-not-kill some being (capable or understanding or not)? Also, if you say killing animals is okay (or "more okay") because they lack understanding, young babies understand probably about as much as animals - I don't think you'll like where that analogy is going.

@NotThatGuy Young babies have the potential to understand more than animals. Pain is harmful because it interferes with thinking. The chief attribute of pain is impairment of the thought processes, where you are forced to focus on the pain and cannot focus well on anything else, and if the pain is severe enough this can last long after it ends, as well (PTSD).

@causative Potentials get you into some really weird moral positions really quickly, but anyway. Pleasure also interferes with thinking. Does that mean pleasure is also bad? If some instance of pain and some instances of pleasure equally interfere with thinking, are they equally bad? You seem to be trying very hard to make your position make sense, with the unavoidable reality that reducing suffering and increasing happiness or well-being is really the thing people care about.

@NotThatGuy Pleasure normally doesn't interfere with thinking to the extent pain does, but yes, it could be as bad. Consider drug addiction. Pain and pleasure are not what people really care about; would you enter a machine that gave you severe dementia but kept you alive and made you happy for 100 years?

@causative Drug addiction is bad because of the long-term negative physical, mental, social and economic effects, all of which contribute to suffering. It's not bad because you're simply thinking less. Regarding 100-year dementia, there'd be too many questions around the conditions and how that would affect others (dementia is strongly associated with suffering, specifically of those around you). For your virtual world example, consider that video games (and also movies and books) are a less immersive shorter-term version of that (but there'd also be questions).

Note that availability of books increases understanding; then, we can apply the repugnant conclusion by using books as a measure of minimum understanding available in a literate society. One might argue that societies based on only one book with only the thinnest semblance to reality are not "best".

I will answer only with regard to the problem of understanding the causes and remedies for suffering. The social efforts to remedy problems associated with the emotional "Check Engine Light".
Baruch Spinoza describes an affect as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. The phrase "accompanied by" means the ideas of cause can be somewhat arbitrary and diverse. In general Spinoza maps or relates a feeling with an idea of cause taken from the set of items with names: self, others, God, or Nature. He argues that an idea of cause can be adequate or inadequate, which I translate to the terms accurate or inaccurate. Aesthetics is the idea that pleasure or pain have arbitrary causes which cannot be properly evaluated as accurate or inaccurate but merely arise in the subjective context of each respective individual. One would hope that feelings of pleasure, beauty, heaven, arise via grace and not feeling of pain, ugliness, hell. Affects are complex and do not always map to accurate sources of cause. Spinoza made strong claims to reduce the affects to patterns similar to geometrical figures. This claim was not convincing.
Thomas Szasz wrote The Myth of Mental Illness. Subsequently his license as a psychiatrist was challenged because he did not believe in mental illness! But Szasz argued that mental illness is a belief system concerning the meaning of behavior. The social context is some persons complain and other persons attempt to provide remedies. This is similar to the pattern where the mechanic repairs the fault to shut off the check engine light.
Szasz describes suffering as persistent pain which tends to cause the suffering person to complain. A person living in a totalitarian regime once stated the inhibition against the complaint. Quote: Complain and get your head bashed in! Szasz is talking about the liberty based system where the medical doctors, justice system, social workers, and so-called mental health workers have an incentive to hear complaints of patients and plaintiffs.
Szasz looks at the pattern of complaints to medical doctors, justice workers, and mental health workers, and the types of remedies they provide, to treat the following:

medical disability or disease
adverse social conditions
unwanted pain not caused by 1 or 2

The experts who try to remedy suffering thus fall into three categories of medicine, social justice work, and mental health helpers that do not perform interventions as medical or social justice work. The ethics in the helper professions are now a mix of medical and justice concerns.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7923912/

Beneficence, nonmaleficence, autonomy, and justice constitute the 4 principles of ethics.

Unfortunately, it is difficult to identify and remedy the actual causes of suffering in all cases. If I could accurately identify a cause of pain, and I can act independently to eliminate that cause of pain, then I can apply prudence, the ability to govern action by the use of reason, and I do not need to ask others for help. But humans obviously have cognitive-behavioral limits on this model that I call Ideal Prudence. We face serious limits in early life on this capacity and we face social limits in adult life.
